# Конфликт роутов yii2 и Vue.js

Tags: yii2, vue.js, url

хочу подружить Vue.js и Yii2. Написал апи на вью, но как дошло дело до фронтенда столкнулся с проблемой: при переходе на роут из вью, улетает запрос на сервер. Как я понял такого быть не должно. Судя по всему проблема в конфигурации юишки. Причем такая трабла только если HistoryMode выключен, но меня не устраивает # в урле, поэтому (как я понял) он должен быть обязательно включен. Так вот, вопрос: как можно добиться, чтобы яичница единожды отправляла индексную страницу, а дальше все роуты обрабатывались вью жсом?

вот код роутов vue.js:

```
const Bar = { template: "<div>bar</div>" }

const routes = [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar },

]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history',
})


const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app')
```

настройки yii:

```
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'projects'],
                '<controller:(\w|-)+>/' => 'site/index',
            ],
        ],
```

P.S. использую базовый шаблон

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался сам. Суть в том, что я вводил адрес напрямую в строку браузера, соответственно вью не обрабатывала запрос и происходил редирект. Для обработки ссылок через Vue необходимо использовать

```
<router-link to="/bar">bar</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть это поможет: [ссылка](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Читал, но не силен в хтаксесах, не знаю как прописать для базового шаблона, если есть готовый буду благодарен